# Display all data from one table regardless info from second table

Tags: mysql, sql

Ineed to display `ALL info from T1 and T2 where T1.Catalogue = T2.Catalogue`

The tables are NOT equal, meaning T2 not necessarily has info for each row of T1, but I need BOTH TABLES to be displayed anyway.

How do I do this please?

This will not produce what I want:

```
select master.*, digital_info.* from master 
INNER JOIN digital_info on master.Catalogue = digital_info.Catalogue;
```

neither will LEFT JOIN produce:

```
select master.*, digital_info.* 
from master 
LEFT JOIN digital_info 
on master.Catalogue = digital_info.Catalogue;
```

[[[ sorry perhaps my question was rather confusing... i've amended it ]]]

Comment: to avoid all this JOIN messages: select master.*, digital_info.* 
from master INNER JOIN digital_info 
on master.Catalogue = digital_info.Catalogue; - this will not produce what i want.

Comment: Are you wanting ALL the data from both T1 AND T2 regardless of a match, e.g. a full outer join?

Comment: Yes! outer join perhaps it is?

Comment: Left Join is shorthand for Left Outer Join - but a Full Outer Join would return all rows from T1 and T2 regardless of the match clause, I only pick up on that from the 'ALL info from T1 and T2' - reading that in isolation suggests full outer join but it is not entirely clear if that is what you are after

Comment: Please post some example data and some expected results.

Comment: i've amended my original post with examples..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from master as m
 left outer join digital_info as d on m.Catalogue = d.Catalogue 
union
select * from master as m
 right outer join digital_info as d on m.Catalogue = d.Catalogue;
```

is this what you are looking for?

Comment: this produces error - Error Code: 1051. Unknown table 'master', which don't make sense?

Comment: @Elen what are the 2 table names

Comment: @Elen try not using the `master` word as a table name since it is reserved word in mysql.And try the updated answer.

Comment: the updated example seem to work! but i just need to do some tests

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM 
T1 LEFT JOIN  T2
ON T1.Catalogue = T2.Catalogue
```

LEFT JOIN: Each item in the left table will show up in a MySQL result, even if there isn't a match with the other table that it is being joined to.

Comment: @Elen: consider the word `LEFT JOIN` in the query. I don't know what you really want but all the answers here are correct according to the question you asked.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM T1 LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.Catalogue = T2.Catalogue;
```

> The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all rows from the left table (table_name1), even if there are no matches in the right table (table_name2).
>   [(http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)

Comment: sorry, this is too simple - this will select ONLY matched elements between two tables, but i need ALL elements form T1. but thanks

Comment: As I stated this code will display any matches in your left table (T1) regardless of the data in table you are joining (T2)... you are using an `INNER JOIN` in your question which will only return a row if there is a match in both tables. `LEFT JOIN` functions differently

Comment: I don't think you are fully explaining what you want.

Comment: sorry i've amended my question

Answer (score 2):

This is called a left join. Example:

```
SELECT *
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.Catalogue = T2.Catalogue
```